Critical network events
I am managing a complex network with multiple devices and applications and I need a reliable way to be alerted immediately if a critical device fails or network connectivity is disrupted.
I believe a robust network monitoring solution that can monitor your network devices, applications, and services 24/7 and send alerts via email, SMS, or other channels when issues arise can help me achieve this. Please suggest such tools.

Prometheus for monitoring and alerting:
https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
If you want a graphical front end for displaying realtime data or searching historical data from Prometheus then also Grafana:
https://grafana.com/grafana/
To install grafana in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:
sudo snap install grafana

